# Запретить переход на jsp страницу

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Здравствуйте. Как запретить пользователям, явно открывать jsp страницу.
Например : `site.ru/main.jsp`. Есть сервлет с url `"/home"`. Хочу оставить только такой доступ `"site.ru/home"`. Подскажите, как подобное реализовать?

Comment: Возможно подойдет редирект в `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Храните свои .jsp в каком-нибудь каталоге в WEB-INF. Из сервлета к ним доступ будет, а снаружи к WEB-INF доступ всегда закрыт